# How to remove traces of a disconnected hard drive from windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-registry, uninstall

My alternate drive has been failing for a while, and after several hangups trying to start the computer, I decided I had enough and disconnected the hard drive from the computer. Going through add or remove programs, I have found several programs still listed from that drive, and can't uninstall because the drive doesn't exist anymore.

I have tried running CCleaner to remove the registry listings, and I have run sfc /scannow. not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

All those programs refer this drive for a purpose - want to read/write some resources. You need to solve this case by case possibly by reinstalling some software but if you belive those are only related to things like last save path you can do following trick.
Let say your system drive is **C:** and disconnected drive was **D:** You can create folder
**C:\D_Drive** and map it with command:

`subst d: C:\D_Drive`

You can leave it empty or just put basic folder's structyre like 'program files' or put full content you were able to recover from old drive. Then periodically review it's content and reconfigure the software to not use it. After you realize it's no longer needed you can unmap with command:

`subst D: /D`

Comment: My goal is to have those programs disappear from "installed programs". So in order to get these removed from my computer, I need to make a d_drive and reinstall the programs and then uninstall all of them?

Comment: to just remove from add/remove programs go to registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and delete appropriate. You will need remove  start menu and desktop items seperately